# The return value of javascript methods

Tags: javascript, methods

```
var john = { 
    fullName: "John Smith",
    age: 30,
    mass: 68, 
    height: 179,
    calcBMI: function() {
      this.mass / this.height;
    }
};                                                                              

console.log(john.calcBMI);
```

When I run the `console.log` method get return value of

```
[Function: calcBMI]
```

I expected an float object. I don't know where to start to fix this. I want the method calcBMI to return the mass of john / the height of john.
I also tried the key word `return`

Comment: You forgot to call the function. You need `()`s after a function to call it. You also forgot the `return` keyword in the code posted

Comment: thanks, I am from a ruby background. Those ruby habits are so ingrained in me.

Answer (score 2):

If your property in an object has a function as value you have to call that property name with a function call.
and if you want a result from your function use return as below.

```
var john = { 
    fullName: "John Smith",
    age: 30,
    mass: 68, 
    height: 179,
    calcBMI: function() {
      return this.mass / this.height; // this will return computed result(mas/height).
    }
};
```

now call your method
john.calcBMI() to get result of calcBMI function.

```
john.calcBMI(); // print this statement to view result.
console.log('value >>>',john.calcBMI());
```

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly need to *call* the function itself (i.e. `calcBMI()` vs `calcBMI`) and the function itself needs to *return* the result of your calculation via a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) statement:

```
calcBMI: function() {
  return this.mass / this.height;
}
```

And then simply call it as a function as seen below:

```
console.log(john.calcBMI());
```

Attempting to just call `calcBMI` without the parentheses to execute it would just return the definition of the function itself, which is why your previous log message indicated a function.